# Get IWin32Window Parent Handle in VSTO Addin to Center saveFileDialog

Tags: c#, vsto

I have an Outlook 2013 VSTO addin.  I'm trying to center my saveFileDialog on the parent.  I read that you can overload the ShowDialog() method with a IWin32Window handle.  I can't find any examples to show how to get this IWin32Window handle.  How can I get the IWin32Window handle for Outlook so I can pass it to ShowDialog() and center the saveFileDialog() on the parent window.

From what I read just passing in the handle isn't enough.  Seems there is an extra step but I can't for the life of me find it.

If anyone can provide an example of how to capture the handle and then center the window on the parent for a saveFileDialog() it would be a huge help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the IWin32Window interface to pass it to the Show or ShowDialog method of the Form class. For example, you can use the following code:

```
 public class WindowHandle : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
 {
      public WindowHandle(IntPtr handle)
      {
          _hwnd = handle;
      }

      public IntPtr Handle
      {
          get { return _hwnd; }
      }

      private IntPtr _hwnd;
   }
```

To get the window handle you can convert an instance of the Explorer or Inspector class to the [IOleWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. The [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687282(v=vs.85).aspx) method allows to retrieve a handle to the window.

Comment: I'm not using a form, just saveFIleDialog directly.  Would this work for that as well?  Would passing the handle to ShowDialog() be enough?  What else do I need to do to center it on the parent from there?  If you can help me with these questions I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Try to specify the parent window handle.

Comment: Yeah I am with the code you gave me .  Will it work for a `saveFileDialog()` tho?  It isn't created with winforms.   There is no `saveFileDialog.StartPosition` like there is for a form... What method would I use to achieve this once I have the handle and pass it to `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Thanks, in addition to my last content I'm getting a warning on  `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()`  The warning is:  AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId has been deprecated because it does not provide a stable Id when managed threads are running on fibers (aka lightweight threads).  To get a stable identifier for a managed thread, use the ManagedThreadId property on Thread.  How can I fix this warning?  I 've searched for ManagedThreadID can't even find the docs for it.  The examples I've found were completely different.